# When sending a Drupal database to a developer, how can I remove users' personal info (e-mail addresses, passwords)?

Tags: users

How can I remove users' e-mail addresses and passwords when sending a database to a developer (for investigating a bug, etc.)?  The e-mail addresses and passwords are irrelevant for the bug and, although I have not consulted with a lawyer, this seems to be a general safe practice.

Comment: suggestion: make a copy to your database, then delete all users in user table except user 0 and 1 then dump the new database and send it to the developer

Comment: I think Drupal.org is sanitizing its database content, when they create a development site for drupal.org, which is used to implement features. I cannot find the documentation, at the moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Drush supports an `sql-sanitize` function:

```
    $ drush help sql-sanitize Run sanitization operations on the current database.

    Options:

    --db-url=<mysql://root:pass@127.0.0.1/db  A Drupal 6 style database URL.
    Only required for initial install - not re-install.

    --sanitize-email        The pattern for test email addresses 
                        in the sanitization operation, or    
                        "no" to keep email addresses         
                        unchanged.  May contain replacement  
                        patterns %uid, %mail or %name.       
                        Default is "user+%uid@localhost".

--sanitize-password     The password to assign to all        
                        accounts in the sanitization         
                        operation, or "no" to keep passwords 
                        unchanged.  Default is "password".   


    Aliases: sqlsan
```

You could always setup a clone of your live site using `drush archive-dump` or `drush sql-sync` then run `sql-sanitize` on that cloned sites db and get everything cleaned. I believe `sql-sanitize` provides a hook so you can sanitize custom drupal data you deem sensitive beyond the scope of the default username and password.

Comment: When sanitizing e-mails, it's often an excellent idea to change e-mails to @example.com, as that prevents anyone from accidentally sending out a lot of e-mails.